# Woocommerce - How to call get_email_restrictions() in WC_Coupon class?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to get the list of customer usage restrictions for a specific coupon. My (broken) code is:

```
<?php
$coupon = new WC_Coupon('couponcode');
print_r($coupon->get_email_restrictions());
?>
```

How to solve?

Comment: Are you expecting a value from this function? Is the value set in $coupon? What about:
    print_r(get_email_restrictions($coupon));

Comment: @JeromeWileySegovia yes I'm expecting an array with list of user that can use "couponcode" coupon. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-coupon.php

Comment: Also, you can try:
```krumo($coupon);
krumo(get_email_restrictions());```

http://krumo.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @JeromeWileySegovia I don't think wordpress has krumo function like Drupal...

Comment: Just saw a use case on hotexamples and it seems you can actually use it in the syntax you have above. However, I did notice they seem to wrap it in an is_array() for some reason.

`if (is_array($coupon->get_email_restrictions()) && sizeof($coupon->get_email_restrictions()) > 0) {
                    $check_emails = array();`